# capture screen, save on server and stream it to end users

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to record the screen of the user. basically what the flow is,

1. the application will capture the user's screen
2. store it on server( images)
3. convert the images in avi
4. display the avi to the end user

Any idea will be of great help

Comment: are you planning to show users desktop in a video to the user himself. Is it some kind of spy app... any way you can't do that from an ASP.Net app.. you need a Desktop app installed locally to do this and upload images to server...^^if that was possible then  hacker can be having a Live telecast of my Desktop.^^

Answer (score 2):

I think a web app cannot do that, extensions are possible or maybe a real software installed on the clients machine

Comment: well you are right.. i need a windows based app on client system that will stream the user's screen on server... and web application that will display the stream to the end user... my problem is to capture user's screen and save on server.. how to do that...any famous third party tool

Answer (score 0):

You could install [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) servers on your clients, and a VNC client on your server. Your server's VNC client could connect to your clients' VNC servers, capture the video stream, and eventually play it back when you want it played back.